# Magma CAS. Finding all d in [1..100] such that x^3+y^3=d for x,y in the rationals

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

```
> One := procedure();                         
procedure> P2<x,y,z> := ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(),2);
procedure> for i := 1 to 100 do
procedure|for> C_i := Curve(P2, x^3+y^3-i*z^3);
procedure|for> E_i, C_itoE_i := EllipticCurve(C_i);
procedure|for> G, map := MordellWeilGroup(E_i);
procedure|for> print Generators(E_i);
procedure|for> end for;
procedure> end procedure;


> One;
procedure() ... end procedure
```

This method is only printing out "procedure() ... end procedure" for some reason. I honestly have no idea why, I tried fixing it but in prev. codes C_i and E_i were valid concepts inside a for loop.
You don't have to tell me the exact mistake or even know Magma but if you can help work with me through this problem that'd be great (like teamwork?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the procedure:

```
> One();
```

(It's been a long time since I've done anything with Magma, but it looks like `One;` on its own evaluates to the procedure itself.)

Comment: You're right. Hmm.. it's amazing I spend many many minutes trying to correct a program error and it's really something as simple as this. Thanks very much! Maybe others will find the question useful some day.